# Careers 2.0 advertisement formatted as a simple bullet list

Tags: bug, status-norepro, stack-overflow, jobs, design

Please find the below two images

#### Careers 2.0 Section: Usual Display

> [image: Careers 2.0 Display]

#### Careers 2.0 Section: Unusual Display

> [image]

Today only, I found this issue in Stack Overflow. It appears that one of the adverts for Careers 2.0 is not being displayed correctly. Can anyone provide your thoughts on this?

#### Update:

I am able to reproduce this issue. I wonder why the CSS components not getting loaded, my Internet connection speed is 8MB/sec. Please check the below screenshot having the console log for your reference.

> [image]

Comment: @Avadhani, It appears to be an issue with the stylesheets not loading correctly. Are you getting the issue consistently upon refresh?

Comment: Yes, Today I have seen this uncertainty not less than 20 times...

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this. If you're using Chrome, can you check the Network tab in Developer Tools and see if there are any resources that are failing to load?

Comment: I reproduced this, FWIW. http://i.imgur.com/xHnUyXa.png

Comment: I've got this on occasion as well; it's normally when my internetz connection is playing up...

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards Malfunctioning internets have caused stylesheets to fail a few times in my browsing career. Seems plausible.

Comment: @rossipedia can we hope this issue can be resolved??

Comment: @AvadhaniY it can't be resolved because it can't be reproduced by the developers team.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I am able to reproduce the issue. Not only me, Please see the comments above. I have updated my question.

Comment: @rossipedia I am able to reproduce the issue. Please check my updated question with the screenshot displaying an error.

Comment: @AvadhaniY you need to write down exactly steps you did in order to make it happen over and over again, that is what reproduce it is about. Then the developers will follow your steps and try to reproduce it if they can.

Comment: Well, from what I've seen [this is the CSS file responsible for that sidebar](http://cdn-careers.sstatic.net/careers/gethired/sidebar.min.css?v=17be6ca0db4b) - try browsing directly to it and see what error you get.

Comment: @AvadhaniY The websockets error is not causing the CSS issue. I need exact steps to reproduce the issue. Right now everything seems to indicate an issue with you being unable to download the CSS file necessary to style that side bar.